# escape from a linux cli for loop

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I'm doing something like this:

```
for f in `find -iname '*.html'`; do scp $f remoteserver:$f; done;
```

I've got through about 3 of the 1000 files and I've decided I want to abort the operation.

CTRL+C only escapes the SCP login prompt and takes me to the next one, rather than escaping the for loop.

Is there a better way than hitting CTRL+C 9997 times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should learn to check exit status of processes you run - especially if you run them in a loop:

```
for f in `find -iname '*.html'`; do scp $f remoteserver:$f || break; done;
```

Notice the `|| break` bit.

Answer (score 2):

Simultaneously press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to suspend the task then use `kill %1` to kill that task.

You may find that `xargs` is a better way of achieving this task. Or `rsync`. Or even compressing the HTML files into an archive and `scp`-ing that. But this is probably off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I would normally use xargs and rsync, but I was just using this as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bash 'trap' builtin that traps signals. This way you can trap your Ctrl-C and do ... exit :)

my2c

Comment: Thanks for the info - this is something I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. hitting CTRL+C twice in very quick succession seems to do the trick...

Comment: Yes. That works if you are quick enough ... see my answer for something more reliable ;)

Comment: Ah yes, that's it, he should have hit ctrl-c ***9998*** times!